# set property of master page from content page and get that property value from another content page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page with one property name event type. Now I want to set this property from a content page and then that property value should be available to another content page.

Is this possible with asp.net? If yes then please help me out.

And yes, my content page already inherits another page which is not master.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this property is a custom property that you added to your master page, then you'll have to add a `MasterType` declaration to the page that is incorporating it.

```
<%@ MasterType 
    virtualpath="~/Path/To/Your.master" 
%>
```

This allows the web site or application to know the specific type of the master page at compile time and allows you to access it as you would any other property in a control.

```
Page.Master.MyCustomerProperty = someValue;
```

*Edit: As a side note, in getting this property down to your next control, it would probably be best to create (and raise) a custom event indicating the property has changed. This way a number of controls can subscribe to the event and "self-update" without having to be concerned with the timing of when the property is set.*

**Example:** In your master page you can define an event as a "global" variable. Then in your property you can raise this event.

```
public event EventHandler myPropertyChanged;
public delegate void MyPropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e);

//...

public string MyProperty
{
    get
    {
       return _myProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        _myProperty = value;
        if (myPropertyChanged != null)
            myPropertyChanged(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Then in your other controls, you can subscribe to this event to know when it changes:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Page.Master.MyPropertyChanged += new EventHandler(MasterPropertyChanged);
}

protected void MasterPropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    //Rememeber you need the VirtualType in order for this event to be recognized
    SomeLocalValue = Page.Master.MyProperty;
}
```

A good step-by-step tutorial of this process can be found on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5041/Step-by-Step-Event-handling-in-VB-NET). A good c# custom events tutorial can be found on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I am able to set this property from contentpage ..but when i go to another content page that value is becoming null.how can i preserve that values..which i have recently set.

Comment: @Darshan: Keep in mind that it's not necessarily null. Most likely it's a matter of timing. You are probably attempting to access the property from the other control before it is set. Look at my edit for a solution to that particular problem.

Comment: custom event..I have no idea about that..can u please explain with example bro...that would be great..!!

Comment: @Darshan: Oh sorry about that. I was answering another question at the same time that was in VB. I'll correct it.

Comment: @Darshan: I posted an edit. You should treat this as psuedo code since I haven't had a chance to test this part and I'm riffing from memory.

Answer (score 2):

If your pages are from different requests, a master property will not work.  The master page is not static, there is a different one for each request, which means that the instance you set the value on is gone when you try to retrieve it.  The `Session` dictionary is where you should put user content that you want to persist between requests.

Answer (score 2):

Add a property to the master page:

```
public string lblBannerText { get { return lblBanner.Text; } set { lblBanner.Text = value; } }
```

Then, get the master of the page and cast it to the master class type:

```
((MyMaster)Page.Master).lblBannerText = "banner text";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Master property` of your page and access to your property

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.page.master.aspx

Sample

```
ContentPlaceHolder mpContentPlaceHolder;
    TextBox mpTextBox;
    mpContentPlaceHolder = 
      (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
    if(mpContentPlaceHolder != null)
    {
        mpTextBox = 
            (TextBox) mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("TextBox1");
        if(mpTextBox != null)
        {
            mpTextBox.Text = "TextBox found!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am able to set this property from contentpage ..but when i go to another content page that value is becoming null.how can i preserve that values..which i have recently set

Comment: You can use Session cache in order to persist ,, ViewState is not sufficient

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Create a property in your master page and you access it from content page:

Master page:

```
public partial class BasePage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{ 
   private string[] _RequiredRoles = null;

   public string[] RequiredRoles
   {
     get { return _RequiredRoles; }
     set { _RequiredRoles = value; }
   }
 }
```

Content Page:

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load()
  {
    Master.RequiredRoles = new string[] { //set appropriate roles };
   }
 }
```

Comment: You will need to cast the master page to the correct type unless you use and extension method

Comment: Hello friends I am able to set this property from contentpage ..but when i go to another content page that value is becoming null.how can i preserve that values..which i have recently set.

Answer (score 0):

the easy way to get or set MasterPage's property, just like this.in content page do the follow.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    var master = this.Master as Site;
    master.SiteName += "|网站首页";
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

and define property in master page

```
public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
    public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public SiteSettings siteSettings { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        siteSettings = SettingsFactory<SiteSettings>.Get();
        MetaDescription = siteSettings.SearchMetaDescription;
        MetaKeywords = siteSettings.SearchMetaKeywords;
        SiteName = siteSettings.SiteName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  Here's what I did:

```
//Id the form tag and place a runat server
  <form id="form1" runat="server" >

//In C# Masterpage.cs - Expose the forms properties
 public System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm Form1 {
            get { return form1; }
            set { form1 = value;
            } }
//In C# Consuming page add this to pageLoad using UniqueId
 ((SiteMaster)Page.Master).Form1.DefaultButton = btnSearchUsersLink.UniqueID;
```