# MasterPage objects returning as null

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I've got an ASP.net application that is used to display information queried from our ERP system onto various web pages. The main object is called an EpicorUser, and it basically encapsulates all current information about an employee.

This object is used to fill in a bunch of various fields on the master page such as Full Name, current activity, clock in/out times, etc.

I am trying to pass this object from the MasterPage into the content pages to avoid needlessly querying the WebService that serves this information. The problem is, when I access the object from a ContentPage, it is always null. I know it has been populated because my MasterPage content is all filled in correctly.

I am trying to access the MasterPage 'CurrentUser' object from my ContentPage like this:

```
**MasterPage Codebehind:**
public EpicorUser CurrentUser; //This object is populated once user has authenticated

///This is in my ContentPage ASPX file so I  can reference the MasterPage from codebehind
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Pages/MasterPage/ShopConnect.Master" %>

**ContentPage CodeBehind:**
string FullName = Master.CurrentUser.UserFileData.FullName; //CurrentUser is null(but it shouldn't be)
```

Strange thing is, I had another content page where this system worked fine. It has also stopped working, and I don't think I have changed anything on the masterpage that could cause this. I had set the CurrentUser as a public property so I could access

I went as far a creating a method to re-populate the object from the master page, and calling it from the code-behind on the contentpage:

```
**ContentPage code-behind:**
EpicorUser CurrentUser = Master.GetCurrentUserObject();

**MasterPage Method being invoked:**
public EpicorUser GetCurrentUserObject()
{
    using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "OFFICE"))
    {
        UserPrincipal principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        EpicorUser CurrentEmployee = RetrieveUserInfoByWindowsID(principal.SamAccountName);   
        return CurrentUser; //Object is NOT null before the return
    }
}

**ContentPage code-behind return:**
EpicorUser CurrentUser = Master.GetCurrentUserObject(); //But object is now null once we return
```

Stepping through the code shows me that the CurrentUser object is populated correctly in the MasterPage code behind, *but once it is returned to the ContentPage code behind, it is now null!*

Anyone know where the disconnect is?

Comment: Could this be your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431733/set-property-of-master-page-from-content-page-and-get-that-property-value-from-a i know it worked at one stage but might be worth a read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content Page is loaded first and then Master page will be loaded. So, your property could be blank when it is accessed in the content page. You can try creating a public method(to return UserObject) on the master page and then call the method from content page.

Another option is 
creating a base page class(inherit all content pages) and create a property to return the user object. So, all pages can access the value

EDIT:

```
public class BasePageClass : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public List<string> LookupValues
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["LookupValues"] == null)
            {
                /*
                    * create default instance here or retrieve values from Database for one time purpose
                    */
                ViewState["LookupValues"] = new List<string>();
            }
            return ViewState["LookupValues"] as List<string>;
        }
    }
}
public partial class WebForm6 : BasePageClass
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
    }
    protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //access lookup properties
        List<string> myValues = LookupValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: Argh! I can't believe I didn't realize this is what was happening! Is using a base class and inheriting from it a common practice? I tried using the public method as mentioned above, but ran into the same problem.

Comment: If content pages share lot of common properties and events, it is advisable to create a base page class to avoid repetitive code.

Comment: @LeeHarrison Yes, it's a common practice. You can even set it from web.config so that all your pages automatically inherit from the class. I can't find the link describing how to do that though...

Comment: I agree, it could be something like "AuthenticatedPage" and inherit it from the classes that need "authenticated" behavior.

Comment: I've already began implementing this into my current project, which was actually very easy. This was an extremely helpful/eye-opening tip. However, is there any way to allow the MasterPage to share with this same class even though it is derived from a different object?

Comment: @LeeHarrison I doubt you can enable the master page to share public members without actually inheriting the base class. There could be a way to do it. But, I am not sure