# get dropdownlist value from master page for query parameter on content page

Tags: asp.net

How do I get the value of a dropdownlist on the master page and use that value in the select query in the ASP.Net code on another page? 
I do not want to use the code behind so please do not post any solutions with the code behind, I already know how to do it that way. I want to do all of this in the ASP.Net code.

Comment: I'm not clear about what you mean by "in the select query". Could you show an example of your current "select query".

Comment: The query is really big. It is basically a select query with a where clause. I want to pass the value from the master page to the parameter in the where clause.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine how you could have a SQL statement in an ASP.NET page without using any code-behind.

Comment: Are you using the <asp:SqlDataSource /> control or something?

Comment: yes, I am using <asp:SqlDataSource />. I didn't write the code. Normally I would use the code behind. But since I have probably several hundred pages setup like this I don't want to use the code behind. I could pass a value from the master page from it's code behind into the content page. Not sure how to do that either. I normally just use ASP.Net for creating the layout and then manipulate the data in the code behind.

Comment: Have you tried MasterType like in this SO article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431733/set-property-of-master-page-from-content-page-and-get-that-property-value-from-a?rq=1